# Excel Highlighting First Empty Cell Below An Entry

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007, highlighting

I've been trying for hours what I thought would be simple but clearly is not for me!

I have a column where every ten cells has the word "TRUE" in it, the rest of the cells in between are empty. So it looks as follows:

1. TRUE

2.

3.

4.

5.

6.

7.

8.

9.

10.

11. TRUE

12.

13.....

The excel documents I have are massive and in no way can I go by hand typing in "YES" below every TRUE entry. I've tried formulas but they always end up highlight ALL the empty cells below TRUE. Please help?

1. TRUE
2. YES

3.

4.

5.

10.

11. TRUE
12. YES

13...

Thank you!

Comment: Are you looking to enter "YES" only on the first empty cell after a "TRUE"?

Comment: If you can replace the contents of the other cells that are to remain blank (as in they don't have formulas in them), you might try to highlight about 30 of the rows, then use the drag-fill feature.  Excel is pretty smart with this feature and can usually figure out your pattern.

Answer (score 0):

The approach below might not be a clean one, but it still would work!

Follow the steps  below to populate `YES` below every `TRUE` row:

- Select the data and enable `Filter` over it.
- Now, unselect "TRUE" from the column of interest, so that you will be displaying only the "Blank" rows in that column
- Enter the following formula in each of the blank cells in that column. (Make sure to replace "A" with the column name from your sheet)

> =IF(INDIRECT("A"&ROW()-1)="TRUE","YES","")

This formula will insert an "YES" if the previous row has "TRUE", else it will insert "" (blank).

- Now, clear the filters previously used.

The sheet at each step will look like below,

[image: Excel Steps]

Comment: I've tried this, but I am still getting blanks returned. I used the same formula and essentially the column starts of with the first entry being TRUE. I filtered and everything but it comes back blank, no YES's to be seen anywhere.

Comment: Can you try entering the formula "INDIRECT("A"&ROW()-1) " on any of the rows after TRUE and see if it returns TRUE?

Comment: Yes it does. But then every other blank space becomes TRUE as well. Maybe I should change my "TRUE" inputs into another word?

Comment: Oh wait, I got it to work. The first formula worked better once I retried in a separate book. Thank you so much :)

Comment: may be its a formatting issue where the cells are auto-formatted to be Boolean because of it containing TRUE/FALSE values. Try removing the double quotes surrounding "TRUE" in the formula.

Comment: @Lowzenza glad it worked! like I mentioned above, could be a formatting issue with your other sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Select the column containing the values and run this small macro:

```
Sub YYEESS()
    Dim rng As Range, r As Range
    Set rng = Selection.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    For Each r In rng
        If r.Text = "TRUE" And r.Offset(1, 0).Value = "" Then
            r.Offset(1, 0).Value = "YES"
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```